# Check if Contract variable is undefined

Tags: solidity, contract-development

How can I check if an Contract variable is `undefined` in Solidity?

Answer (score 8):

According to [this](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#in-memory-types)

> Memory-stored objects as local variables are correctly
> zero-initialised: Members of structs and elements of fixed-size arrays
> are recursively initialised, dynamic arrays are set to zero length.
> delete x assigns a new zero-initialised value to x.

There is no such **undefined** variable. All objects are zero-initalised.

Answer (score 4):

By some Solidity coding conventions you add a boolean 'valid' element to any struct to indicate it is undefined (false is the initialized value).

Sometimes I see fields having zero reserved to mean undefined - e.g. treat 0 as an undefined address.  You could also do that for a string, but string is often externally input so you have to make sure someone didn't send you a zero string.

I would advise using a field where zero is naturally meaningful like a separate bool or an existing address element in a struct.

Comment: This is not useful for a pure Contract object isn't it?

Comment: what do you mean by a "pure Contract object"?