# Require that a variable has been defined

Tags: solidity

I want to require two variables for the execution of my function, firstly a string shall not be undefined and then a mapping (address => uint) that shall be undefined. In the latter case, I have user numbers from 0...n, so 0 would be the first user. 
Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to do complicated workarounds with eg. keccak hashes?

```
struct userData {
    string name;
    string role;   
    mapping (address => uint) accountToId;    
}

mapping (address => userData) addressToUserData; 

function register(string _name, string _role) public {
    require(_name !== false); // to avoid empty names
    require(addressToUserData[msg.sender] == false); // make sure mapping is undefined
    addressToUserData[msg.sender] = userData(_name, _role);
}
```

[I hope by now there is better solution than [this]](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/check-if-contract-variable-is-undefined)

Comment: Could you show some code?  It is unclear what do you want so far.

Comment: It's a pretty general question, but I added some code.

Answer (score 0):

```solidity
function register(string memory _name, string memory _role) public {
  require(bytes (_name).length > 0); // to avoid empty names
  require(bytes (addressToUserData[msg.sender].name).length == 0); // make sure mapping is undefined
  addressToUserData[msg.sender] = userData(_name, _role);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you hint with the bytes typecasting. However, it won't work if the mapping maps to an integer, which is the case in my code.
For e.g.
`require(bytes 
(datasets[_dataId].accountToId[_account]).length == 0)`
There is an error:
`TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "bytes memory"`

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Sure, thank you: [link](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xdbaf48282120e0fae89a447cbb7688fb35f68e61#code)

--> function addUserToLoan